# Android source codes or guides on developing an app for Epson LQ-310 Dot Matrix Printer

Tags: printing, driver, epson

I'm looking for some examples or guides to develope an android app for Epson LQ-310 24 pins Dot Matrix Printer. 
So far i have found on an Epson ePOS-Print SDK (Android SDK Plugin) and it is for thermal printer only.

Is it possible to use the Epson ePOS-Print SDK for developing Epson LQ-310 Dot Matrix Printer?
And is there any difference of algorithm between different models of Dot Matrix Printer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question, I would guess you don't really understand anything about what you are asking.

More than likely, the SDK for a printer won't work for a different printer unless the OEM's documentation says it will. That's because the protocols used to communicate with devices evolve over time and are often completely different between device lines. That's true of most device APIs, not just printers.